# Sudoku solver using backtracking, in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sudoku

I wrote the below Sudoku solver, using Backtracking. Would love to hear your comments on the approach, and how I can improve readability/performance:

```
BLANK = '.'

def sudoku(board)
  # find first '.'
  for i in 0...board.length
    for j in 0...board[i].length
      next unless board[i][j] == BLANK

      options = get_options(board, i, j)
      return nil if options.empty? # validity check failed, kill branch

      # put options on board individually, and recurse
      proposed = board.dup
      options.each do |v|
        proposed[i][j] = v
        return proposed if sudoku(proposed)
        proposed[i][j] = BLANK
      end

      # none of the options worked
      return nil
    end
  end

  # base case: the whole board has numbers
  board
end

def get_options(board, row, col)
  # returns the list of potential options for a particular cell based
  # on the game rules:
  # - no repeated numbers in each row
  # - no repeated numbers in a column
  # - no repeated numbers in a block

  options = [*"1".."9"] # all options
  len = board.length

  # remove the options that exist in the same row
  options -= board[row].chars.uniq

  # remove the options that exist in the same column
  column = len.times.collect {|row| board[row][col]}
  options -= column.uniq

  # remove the options that exist in the same block
  block = get_block(board, row, col)
  options -= block.uniq

  # remove blanks and return
  options -= [BLANK]
end

def get_block(board, row, col)
  # returns the entire block that the row/col falls in
  row_start = 3 * (row / 3)
  col_start = 3 * (col / 3)
  block = []

  for i in 0..2
    for j in 0..2
      block << board[row_start + i][col_start + j]
    end
  end
  block
end

board = 
   ["53..7....",
    "6..195...",
    ".98....6.",
    "8...6...3",
    "4..8.3..1",
    "7...2...6",
    ".6....28.",
    "...419..5",
    "....8..79"]

puts sudoku(board).inspect
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems fine to me, I don't know if there is a way to solve this problem that performs better. Some minor things:

- The Ruby std-lib has a matrix class which might help. It also might help to extract the board into its own class with methods like `dup`, `get_row`, `get_column`, `get_block`, `is_blank?`, `is_complete?`
- You don't need to set `proposed[i][j] = BLANK` on each iteration since you are working on a duplicate of the board.
- In `get_options` You don't need to call `uniq`, it should be impossible to get into a state with multiple entries in a row, column or block. Similarly you shouldn't need to remove `BLANK` as there is no way to get a blank entry in the `options` array.

Comment: Strangely, when I remove the `proposed[i][j] = BLANK` line as you suggest, I get `nil`, even though I'm working on a duplicate string. Any idea why? [Demo here](https://repl.it/Huht)

Comment: The `options -= [BLANK]` is actually necessary, since `get_block` can return blanks.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are getting `nil` but `options -= get_block` will not contain a `BLANK` even if `get_block` does. i.e. `[1,2] - [1,BLANK] == [2]`

Comment: Good point on the `BLANK` business -- should've looked closer, you're right!

Comment: That `nil` business is weird indeed -- I'll investigate and post a question to SO separately.

Comment: I'm late to the party but I believe the issue is related to the line **proposed = board.dup**. Since the **board** is an array of arrays, you can't duplicate like this. You need to iterate over it and call **dup** in each of the members.

board.map { |x| x.dup }